# How can I run tests using pytest on a sklearn (leaky) pipeline?

Tags: python, path, pytest, pipeline

My current filestructure:

```
repo/
   |--app/
          |--TextParser.py       <-- Module that needs to be in same folder
          |--models.py           <-- Sklearn pipeline
          |--Main.py
          |--__init__.py
   |--settings.py
   |--tests/
          |--app/
                |--__init__.py
                |--test_file.py  <-- where my tests live
```

**The problem**

Due to this problem of '[leaky pipelines](https://rebeccabilbro.github.io/module-main-has-no-attribute/)', I am more or less forced to combine python files in the same folder as my trained model file. My question is: how can I now test these? No matter from where I run 'pytest', the pipeline has the idea 'baked in' that it has to look inside the same folder as the file that I run the pipeline from... which is always the ../tests/app/test_file.py location. Hence it will always give the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'TextParser'
```

**What I tried**

After trying to run it from different locations, the only option to me seems to be to train the model and somehow make it accept relative paths. Copy pasting all the Modules to tests/ every time you want to test (as importing doesn't work) or creating test files in the app/ area is the opposite of what you should want I think. But retraining the pipeline seems like an unnecessary amount of work; hopefully I'm just missing something interesting.